Computing the Second Exterior Power of Certain Ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ as Modules
I'm working on a problem involving the computation of the second exterior power of certain ideals within the rings $R_1 = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and $R_2 = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$. The problem is as follows:
Let an ideal $I = (2, 1 + \sqrt{-5})$ as an $R_1$-module, I need to verify that the second exterior power $\bigwedge^2 I = 0$.
Let another ideal $J = (2, 1 + \sqrt{5})$ as an $R_2$-module. However, I need to prove that $\bigwedge^2 J \neq 0$.
Any insights on these computations or the underlying structure of the exterior power in this setting would be greatly appreciated.

Are you sure $J$ is an ideal in $R$? Specifically, is $\sqrt5$ in $R$?

Sorry, I need to modify the question.For J, we have another R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]

Your use of () around your TeX suggests to me that you might have cut-and-pasted from a source that used \(\), and something got under-escaped in the process.  I changed it to $$, which is the easiest way to get TeX into the MO flavour of MathJax.  I hope that that was all right.

@LSpice Thank you! Now I know how to make the Tex perfectly be viewd

The fact that your ideals have two generators defines a surjection $R^{\oplus 2}\to I$. Now if you can compute $r$ generators for the kernel of that map (aka “syzygies” between your generators), this gives you an exact sequence $R^{\oplus r} \to R^{\oplus 2} \to I \to 0$ presenting $I$, which tensored by $I$ gives $I^{\oplus r} \to I^{\oplus 2} \to I\otimes_R I \to 0$ which then presents $I\otimes_R I$ (and hence $\bigwedge^2 I$ if you want) as a quotient of the free module $R^{\oplus 4}$ by an explicitly generated submodule. But I presently can't remember how we do that “if” part.

Side remark: for  a noetherian domain: then
is Dedekind iff $\bigwedge^2 J=0$ for every ideal $J$
of $A$. This is essentially a restatement of Lemma 6.7 in this paper, but I guess it's well-documented.

See Example 4.5, Example 4.6, and Remark 4.7 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/extmod.pdf.

The two desired results follow from:

Claim. Let $I$ be an ideal of an integral domain $R$.
Assume that $I$ can be generated by $2$ elements but not less. Then the following are equivalent:

The ideal $I$ is projective.
$\bigwedge^2(I) = 0$.
The second Fitting ideal $\operatorname{Fitt}_1(I)$ of $I$ is $R$.



Proof. See Proposition 20.7, Proposition 20.8 and Exercise 20.9.i of [1]. The latter exercise shows in particular that $\operatorname{Fitt}_1(I)$ is the annihilator of $\bigwedge^2(I)$, which is evidently a cyclic $R$-module.

If an ideal $I$ of a quadratic order $\mathfrak{O} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$ with $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, has standard basis ($a$, $d + ef \omega$) (see [2, Lemma 6.2 and 6.5] for definitions and proofs) where $$\omega = \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
\sqrt{m} & \text{ if } m \not\equiv 1 \mod 4, \\
\frac{1 + \sqrt{m}}{2} & \text{ if }  m \equiv 1 \mod 4, \\
\end{array}\right.$$
then $I$ is projective if and only if $$\frac{\gcd(a, d , ef)}{e} = 1.$$
Alternatively (this item contains self-promotion), the ideal $\operatorname{Fitt}_1(I)$ for such an ideal $I$ can be explicitly computed by means of [3, Lemma 6.5.$ii$].
Since $R_1$ is Dedekind, every ideal of $R_1$ is projective. Thus the above claim yields $\bigwedge^2(I) = 0$.
Since $(2, 2 \omega)$, with $\omega = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$, is a standard basis for $J$ in $R_2$, it follows from [2, Lemma 6.5] that $J$ is not projective. Therefore $\bigwedge^2(I) \neq 0$ by the above claim.
Note. The ideal $J$ of $R_2$ is the conductor of $R_2$ in the maximal order $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}]$.


D. Eisenbud, "Commutative Algebra", 1995.
T. Ibukiyama and M. Kaneko, "Quadratic Forms and Ideal Theory of Quadratic", pages 75 - 93, 2014.
L. Guyot, "Equivalent generating pairs of an ideal of a commutative ring", 2018.

